# How do i get a form to stick to my screen when i open a new application

Tags: vb.net

Whenever I open my form and then open a new application, like Microsoft Edge, the application is not there any more I am working with VB.NET.

Comment: Perhaps you could set your form's `TopMost` property to `True`. Then it will always stay on top of other forms/windows (unless those other forms have set TopMost to True as well).

Comment: [How do I create a topmost window that is never covered by other topmost windows?](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20110310-00/?p=11253) -- [Extending the Desktop](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/extending-the-desktop-bumper) -> [Using Application Desktop Toolbars](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/application-desktop-toolbars)

Answer (score -1):

No sense in reinventing the wheel...

```
<DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError:=True)> _
Private Shared Function SetWindowPos(ByVal hWnd As IntPtr, ByVal hWndInsertAfter As IntPtr, _
                                     ByVal X As Integer, ByVal Y As Integer, ByVal cx As Integer, _
                                     ByVal cy As Integer, ByVal uFlags As UInt32) As Boolean
End Function

ReadOnly HWND_TOPMOST As New IntPtr(-1)
Shared ReadOnly SWP_NOSIZE As UInt32 = Convert.ToUInt32(&H1)
Shared ReadOnly SWP_NOMOVE As UInt32 = Convert.ToUInt32(&H2)

Private Sub Timer1_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    'Either one of these does the trick
    SetWindowPos(Me.Handle, HWND_TOPMOST, 0, 0, 0, 0, SWP_NOMOVE Or SWP_NOSIZE)
    'Me.TopMost = True
End Sub
```

Source:

https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/91830/Making-a-Form-stay-on-top-of-ALL-other-application

Comment: I just tried setting the `TopMost` property. Worked great for me. I don't understand why all this WinAPI-crap around `SetWindowPos` is necessary in VB.NET apps... The article you link to does not explain this as well. No wonder that answer has just one star out of five...

Comment: Well... explaining the (dis)advantages of `SetWindowPos` might indeed be a bit off-topic here, so my apologies if I was a bit harsh in my first comment. Anyway, I just tried in a VB.NET WinForms testapplication to allow toggling the form's `TopMost` property with a checkbox. That works perfectly fine as well. So honestly I have no clue which technical problems the poster of that linked question on CodeProject had ten years ago using Visual Studio 2008, but when using current versions of Visual Studio 2019 and .NET Framework, the form's `TopMost` property seems to work just fine.

Comment: @BartHofland Listen, I get where you're coming from, I prefer to keep everything within the Framework itself as well, and always try to use it before going to the API, but there's no good reason to "limit your powers" with whatever is available to you as a programmer, and the Win API is still an excellent resource to have at your disposal.

Comment: @BartHofland  That said, SO isn't the end-all-be-all solution provider; it's a place where programmers give you options to solve a problem (as always, there are many ways to solve the same problem), and give you ideas to help get you pointed in the right direction when you're lost on an issue, and this answer certainly fits that criteria. Based on your tone I have to assume you're the downvoter (could be wrong though), and no reason to downvote a "possible" solution to the OP's problem. Others can always chime in with their own answers and the one with the most upvotes "wins".

Comment: Actually, this is a nice example about knowing when to "limit your powers" with whatever is available to you as a programmer. Don't introduce a dependency if you do not need it. Furthermore, from a .NET perspective, I strongly disagree that the Windows API is "an excellent resource for use in .NET applications". It's native, non-managed, Windows-specific code. It's just a backdoor, a dubious fallback option for the extremely rare cases where the .NET Frameworks cannot provide the desired functionality. It would actually make me consider my design choices up to architectural levels.

Comment: However, what striked me most in your answer, is that you only provided a copied answer without any additional clarifications except a reference to the originating source. A source which provides just as much additional explanations as your own answer: none. So to be honest, if I were a beginning developer, I would be totally unaware that this answer would *not* point me in the right direction. It unnecessarily focuses on a Windows API based solution and so it would just add to my confusion. Hence my downvote (indeed).

Comment: That said, I do not understand which "criteria" your answer really fulfills. I have provided my answer simply as a comment to the OP's question, because it just seemed obvious to me and I don't want to seriously get caught up in providing a solution for something I consider to be a flawed design (since topmost windows rigorously break with default window rendering behavior). So I actually don't care about "winning" here.